# Url rewriting not working on my site

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a subdomain for guitar chords for example.
http://tabs.sitename.com/?song=song_name
and i want to rewrite this url to,
http://tabs.sitename.com/song/song_name
I tried using the following code but my url didn't rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^song/([^/]*)/$ /?song=$1 [L]
```

The url didn't rewrite. Did i miss anything? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/\?(song)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /$1/$2? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^song/([^/]+)/$ /?song=$1 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the pattern you supplied:

```
^song/([^/]*)/$
```

does not match the string you are trying to match:

```
song/Bistarai+Bistarai
```

so, next time it will help to just make sure your pattern works before going on.

Assuming I completely understand what you want to do, this should work (php extension on the redirect destination file is just an example, use whatever your real destination file is):

```
RewriteRule ^song\/([A-Za-z0-9\+]+) file_you_want_to_redirect_to.php?song=$1
```

As I mentioned I used a php script in the above example; if I am to understand that you were trying to redirect to the index page of  http://tabs.musiccafenepal.com/, you should know that you should have put

```
index.php?song=$1
```

instead of

```
/?song=$1
```

as the redirect destination expression.

Comment: Thank you for replying but sorry to say that didn't work. I don't know what is the problem here..

Comment: I tested it, the above code works; maybe you have a configuration problem. What actual file is your redirect destination?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by redirect destination, but the file that queries and and controls all the data is index.php, i tried lots of codes but i couldn't rewrite the url, what kind of configuration problem can occur? can you help me with this? thank you

Comment: So this doesn't work?:
    RewriteRule ^song\/([A-Za-z0-9\+]+) index.php?song=$1

Comment: No, that didn't work. Btw the .htacess file is kept at the root folder even if the rewrite should be done to the subdomain i.e, tabs.musiccafenepal.com right?? Can i show you my php codes and files structure so that it will be easy for you to help me?? can you give me your email address?